# change wordpress theme by url parameters

Tags: php, wordpress

Turns out that I forgot to place a semicolon in my functions.php file and now it crashed the whole site:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /home/content/xx/xxxxxxx/html/wp-content/themes/clean-home/functions.php on line 404
```

I don't have FTP access, nor cPanel or hosting access, I was edditing the site accross wp-fileManager plugin.

I've lost all hope with this, and Im wondering if there is a way to switch the theme via url parameters? the admin session is still active.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress uses the following url to activate a theme.

```
/wp-admin/themes.php?action=activate&stylesheet=twentyfourteen&_wpnonce=71e651d2a3
```

The only problem is, you need to know the value for the _wponce url parameter. It might be in your browsers history from a previous request?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this the following way:

as this was a shared hosting account, I didn't have access to the site ftp account, but I had access to other site ftp under the same account. (client mistaked credentials)

So, I uploaded the following php file in the other ftp account:

```
$out = shell_exec ("cat /dev/null >  /absolute/path/to/functions.php");
echo $out;
```

and this whiped the functions.php functions which I later updated.

I answer my own question if someday it helps someone.